# Poll on Akka Streams Graph completion

Tags: akka-stream

I have used akka streams graph for implementing certain use case. Now, I have one big complete graph, which is composed of several partial graphs. Final result is getting computed in the sink once merged from all partial graphs' outputs. This output is then returned to the calling method. 
Now, my problem is that there are times when the graph does not complete running and the result is returned which of course is invalid. Are there any methods provided in the akka framework to wait/poll on the running graph?